# document.getElementById('TextBox1').value is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i wanted to get the value of my textbox in javascript. this is my javascript-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var submitted = false;  var type;
    window.onbeforeunload = function () { 
        if (!submitted) { 
            return "Are you sure you want to leave this page, your test will not be saved?"+type; 
        }
    }; 

    document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit = function () { 
        type=document.getElementById('TextBox1').value; 
        submitted = true;
    }; 
</script>
```

no matter what i type it does not give me the value of textbox1

Comment: Where is the textbox?

Comment: If your code comes *before* the element in the HTML source, it won't work. Move the `<script>` to the end of the body.

Comment: @Pointy What?? The issue is in the submit handler. Though if the code is before the form, then ...

Comment: In the code you've `TextBox1` as `id`, in the text there's `textbox1`. A wrong id in `gEBI()`? Have you taken a look at the console for errors?

Comment: post your complete code

Comment: Two obvious possibilities... firstly (as @Pointy says) if the script is before the HTML, then it needs to be moved to the end of the body, or wrapped in a function that is only called once the page has loaded.  Secondly, if it's `ASP.NET` then the chances are the textbox is within a UserControl or you're using MasterPages or you're using a template based container, it won't be called `TextBox1` it will be called something else... in which case try `document.getElement("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var submitted = false; var type;
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('#form1').submit(function ()
            {
                type = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
                submitted = true;
            });
            window.onbeforeunload = function ()
            {
                if (!submitted)
                {
                    return "Are you sure you want to leave this page, your test will not be saved?" + type;
                }
            };
        });



    </script>
```

if you want to display type's value in alert box then,change if(!submitted') to if(submitted) and you will receive an alert with type value.hope this will do.

Comment: Where does the OP mention any use of jQuery?  (Hint, they don't... if you're going to use jQuery in your answer, then you need to highlight that they'll need to include the jQuery library.)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like just a logic problem:

When you run `onsubmit`, it sets `submitted` to true, and then it runs `onbeforeunload`. Right now it it basically only returns the input value if you've not run `onsubmit`. If you take the `!` out of `(!submitted)`, it will give you an alert with the input's value.